# How to make AWS ECS Task Definition make EC2 instances publicly accessible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

Below is my AWS Task Definition for ECS.

I need every EC2 instance of this task to have port 3026 publicly accessible to the world. How can I modify this JSON to do that?

Currently, after service is running this task, I manually find the EC2 instance(s) and then I manually add a security group that allows ingress from 0.0.0.0/0 on that port.

But I really want to know how to make this JSON do it so I no longer have to do it manually.

```
{
    "family": "myproj",
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "memory": 500,
            "memoryReservation": 350,
            "name": "myproj",
            "image": "blah.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myproj:latest",
            "essential": true,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 3026,
                    "containerPort": 8000,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "entryPoint": [
                "./entrypoint_deployment.sh"
            ],
            "environment" : [
                { "name" : "DB_HOST", "value" : "blah.blah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/myproj",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggested approach is to configure an ECS service associated to your task, and then use an Application Load Balancer (ALB) to route the public traffic to this service.

This guide should help you: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/microservice-delivery-with-amazon-ecs-and-application-load-balancers/

Another (cheaper) option is to use the EC2 instance metadata API provided by Amazon, read the instance_id value from that API and use the "aws-cli" utility to update the security group when your container starts. A script like this should work (to run inside the container):

```
export SECURITY_GROUP=sg-12345678
export INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id INSTANCE_ID --groups $SECURITY_GROUP
```

You need to set the `SECURITY_GROUP` accordingly and have the aws ec2 utility installed in the docker image of the task that you are running.
Furthermore, you need to change the `ENTRYPOINT` of your task docker image to run the script, for example:

```
"entryPoint": [
                "./script_to_setup_SG.sh && ./entrypoint_deployment.sh"
            ],
```

Comment: Doesn't an ALB cost extra money? I am building a toy application and would like to do it at minimal cost. I have only a single task running a single container without any autoscaling. So in this case, isn't an ALB pointless?

Comment: @SaqibAli: yes, ALB costs extra money. I updated the answer with a proposed solution that uses the EC2 instance metadata API.